# How to find the number of data added in CStringArray

Tags: c++, cstring

Helo guys,
        I am working wid CStringArray and i want to know how to find the number of datas added in a CStringArray .  in the below i have a defined the size of the array as 10 but i have added only three 3 data,So i want to know the number of data's added to the array.(here its 3).Is there any way we can do it in CStringArray to find the number of data's added to array

> CStringArray filepaths[10] =
>   {path1.path2,path3};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CStringArray::GetCount()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz4dbsa9(VS.80).aspx)

**Edit:**  In your code above you have actually created an array of CStringArray's.  I am presuming you mean CStringArray from the Microsoft MFC library?

I think you want to be doing something like:

```
CStringArray filepaths;
filepaths.Add( path1 );
filepaths.Add( path2 );
filepaths.Add( path3 );
filepaths.GetCount(); //should ==3
```

Comment: int test = filepaths[10].GetCount();

no its not working its giving a large value..
i tried that before

Comment: I edited the answer to add more information.  I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish, if so please clarify.

Comment: nope its was'nt working..wat i did was..i switched to CString* instead of CStringArray.....